# ImageResizeMode in react-native

Tags: react-native

React native style information [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#style) for an Image mentioned an `ImageResizeMode` enum, but I don't know how to import it.

For `resizeMode`, I'd rather use the enum than inline string literal.

```
import { ImageResizeMode } from 'react-native';
```

but i get:

> ImageResizeMode is undefined

Comment: Enum really just means "one of" in this case. So you are supposed to actually use the explicit value, afaik.

Comment: @NoahAllen That may have been what I thought too, except from the docs next to the resizeMode prop "Object.keys(ImageResizeMode)" which indicates that somewhere there is an ImageResizeMode object with keys representing the possible values.

Comment: "import ImageResizeMode from './node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/ImageResizeMode.js';" works, but seems wrong.

Comment: The possible values are not exported in the source code of Image or in any other way either in react-native. Seems bad indeed. A quick search turns up the type with a commit message of "RN: Replace `ImageResizeMode` w/ Flow Type"
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?q=ImageResizeMode&unscoped_q=ImageResizeMode but it cannot be accessed in a proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In previous versions of RN it was available as a property on `Image` so you would be able to do `Image.resizeMode.cover` just by importing the `Image` class. However the core team decided to go away from this (see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20177), so the correct way is actually to use the string values .. or create your own enum if you like.

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

`import { Image } from 'react-native';`

and then:

```
<Image
  style={{flex: 1}}
  source={require('../PATH')}
  resizeMode="SOME_VALUE"
/>
```

which `SOME_VALUE`

> can be `contain`, `cover`, `stretch`, `center`, `repeat`.

Comment: "For resizeMode, I'd rather use the enum than inline string literal."

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This answer expects the usage of an inline string literal such as 'contain' or 'cover' rather than ImageResizeMode.contain or ImageResizeMode.cover. If I were to use this answer, I wouldn't have asked the question to begin with.